# What are the steps to be undertaken while writing a .install file for drupal 7 module?

Tags: 7, installation

I want to add an table to the database using .install file of a module. I am 
creating a completely new module which has not been enabled till now.

Which are the functions required in the .install file

```
function [HOOK]_install() {
  switch ($GLOBALS['db_type']) {
    case 'mysql':
    case 'mysqli':
//Should I write my query to create table inside this ...
    case 'pgsql':

   break;
}
}


function [HOOK]_uninstall() {
//Should I write the code here to remove the table after installation


}
```

Comment: There are a bunch of different hooks for install files, listing them out isn't going to do anyone much good as [that's already been done](http://definitivedrupal.org/resource/install-hooks). [`hook_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) is for defining custom tables, the example on the docs page should be everything you need. None are required, your implement what you need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Clive says you should use hook_schema for creating your custom tables and then 
hook_update_N
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7
for the updates of your tables module.